# efficient way for reading credential files

Tags: java, filereader

I have to read two text files containing credential information about the database connection and the user email account for some java applications.
This is going to be done in a few different projects, so i decided to move it to a separate class.
I did create this class for reading the database credentials

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GetDbCredentials {
   public static String USR;
   public static String PSW;
   public static String DB;

    public GetDbCredentials(String filePath){
        readFile(filePath);
    }
    public void readFile(String file){
         try {
             if(new File(file).exists()){
                 BufferedReader fr=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                 String input;
                 String[] credentials;

                 while ((input=fr.readLine())!=null){
                     credentials=input.split("::");

                    switch (credentials[0]){
                        case "Username":
                            USR=credentials[1];
                            break;
                        case "Password":
                            PSW=credentials[1];
                            break;
                        case "DataBase":
                            DB=credentials[1];
                            break;                      
                    }
                 }
                 fr.close();            
             }              
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();           
         }
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return PSW;
    }
    public String getUser(){
        return USR;
    }
    public String getDb(){
        return DB;
    }       
}
```

and this works,

```
System.out.println("psw:\t"+new GetDbCredentials(args[0]).getPassword());
System.out.println("usr:\t"+new GetDbCredentials(args[0]).getUser());
System.out.println("DB:\t"+new GetDbCredentials(args[0]).getDb());
```

Now i would have to create, more or less, the same thing on a different class, to read the email information. I was just thinking if there is a better way to handle these, and maybe get a way to add the two classes together.
Maybe calling a class `GetCredentials("email","emailfile.txt")`using the string argument to realize which of the two i need to read, since the email information file contains a list of recipients I cant use the exact same methods

**Extra information:**
I am not concerned about safety. These applications will be run on a safe system. I just want a way for the user to be able to change the information provided and not be hard-coded nor be viewable on the Internet(under git and so on)

Database information file

> Password:: password
>   Username:: username
>   DataBase:: url:port

Email information file

> Password:: password
>   Username:: username
>   recipients:: email1@example.com email2@emample.com

Thank you all,
I went for this solution then

```
public class GetCredential {
private String fileName;

    public GetCredential(String file){
        this.fileName=file;
    }   
    public String getProp(String title){

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            return prop.getProperty(title);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
        }
    }
```

and while calling the class i pass the file and the property I want

```
System.out.println("psw:\t"+new GetCredential(args[0]).getProp("Password"));
System.out.println("usr:\t"+new GetCredential(args[0]).getProp("Username"));
System.out.println("DB:\t"+new GetCredential(args[0]).getProp("DataBase"));

System.out.println("psw:\t"+new GetCredential(args[1]).getProp("Password"));
System.out.println("usr:\t"+new GetCredential(args[1]).getProp("Username"));
System.out.println("DB:\t"+new GetCredential(args[1]).getProp("Recipients"));
```

Comment: can you share your input txt files which you want to use? or atleast their file structures

Comment: I was just thinking about doing that. Doesnt really matter, i can choose any format i want and can ask the users to follow it

Comment: `java.lang.Properties` is the standard for that in the java language. If you can choose the format, then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a properties file? Is far easy to read and write properties files and individual properties.

Example property file:

```
database=database
user=user
password=password
```

Comment: how do you use property files? never used them before

Comment: are you talking about java.lang.Properties as fluminis mentioned? if so, can the properies file be written on a text editor? i am not going to create the properties, the user will enter them manually and i will just read

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)
to load the your property file. You can see sample example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/)